# Possible resolution error for vtk

Tags: vtk

I'm trying to visualize the vtk data given here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/51kjftvdko3g6s8/wEe88Id9QN. I'm doing something wrong which probably is related to resolution. I was wondering if anyone runs this code and sends me the result. If that is more clear than the image I have, it's more likely to be related to graphics driver I  think. In that case, what may be the cause of this problem? The image my computer generates can be found at the dropbox link, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks correct to me (a grid of points is being displayed). If you create a vtkImageData from your vtkStructuredPoints, it will be able to interpolate between the points to display a volume.